# React.js não retorna dados na função map()

Tags: javascript, react, api, maps-javascript-api

Olá, pessoal. Sou iniciante em React.js e gostaria de ajuda com este problema:
Tenho um serviço que executa alguns SELECTs sobre tabelas de um banco Oracle e, com o resultado desses SELECTs, expõe tais dados como uma lista de objetos JSON. Consultando a API pelo browser (Chrome), obtenho estas informações:
[image: Resultado da consulta à API]
Ou seja: a API está retornando os dados corretamente.
Para exibí-los em uma tela da aplicação React, criei este componente:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    carregando: true,
    pedidos: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost:8000/pedidos-bloqueados/";
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(d => {
      this.setState({ pedidos: [d], carregando: false });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.carregando? <div>Carregando...</div> : <div><li> Cliente: * {(this.state.pedidos.map((pedido, index)=>(this.state.pedidos[index]))).map((p, i)=> p['cliente'])}</li></div> } *
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Acontece que, execução da função ***map()*** , dentro do método ***render()*** , é mostrado apenas:

Cliente:

Sem nenhuma informação.
E o componente não pode realizar um ***for()*** no método ***render()*** para iterar sobre os objetos da lista em JSON, então, fiquei sem conseguir visualizar o resultado.
Meu problema está no trecho:

```
{ this.state.carregando? <div>Carregando...</div> : <div><li> Cliente:  {(this.state.pedidos.map((pedido, index)=>(this.state.pedidos[index]))).map((p, i)=> p['cliente'])}</li></div> }
```

Como posso exibir as propriedades de cada objeto da lista no componente ? (**Nota**: *cliente* é apenas ***um dos atributos do objeto JSON retornado [existem outras como **vendedor**, **pedido** , etc.], mas, se eu conseguir listar essa propriedade, posso replicar o comportamento para as demais).

Mais uma vez, agradeço **ENORMEMENTE** qualquer ajuda !

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no primeiro map, você está retornando o index do this.state.pedidos e não o index do pedido que está sendo percorrido.

Alterei um pouco o map para ficar mais legível o problema.

Você está fazendo o seguinte:

```js
this.state.pedidos.map((pedido, index) => {
    return this.state.pedidos[index];
}))
```

Altere para:

```js
this.state.pedidos.map((pedido, index) => {
    return pedido[index];
}))
```

Isso vai resolver o seu problema, mas você pode também parar de setar o **this.state.pedidos** como **[d]** e deixar apenas **d**, dessa forma você poderia remover o primeiro map e deixar apenas o segundo.